# Error al ejecutar el Trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, trigger

Estoy tratando de hacer este trigger pero cuando meto datos dentro de la tabla en concreto me dice que hay un error porque la columna numeroespecies es null... ¿Alguna idea?

```
CREATE DEFINER=`aaronibio`@`%` TRIGGER `especie_terrario_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `especie_terrario` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DECLARE rey_escorpion_achivement INT;
    DECLARE current_id INT;
    DECLARE numeroespecies INT;
    DECLARE numeroanimales INT;
    DECLARE numeroplantas INT;
    DECLARE numerohongos INT;
    
    SELECT idusuario INTO current_id FROM terrarios WHERE id = NEW.idterrario LIMIT 1;
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO rey_escorpion_achivement FROM usuario_logro WHERE idusuario = current_id AND idlogro = 3;   
    
    IF rey_escorpion_achivement = 0 THEN
        INSERT INTO usuario_logro (idusuario, idlogro, fecha_adquisicion) VALUES (current_id, 3,  NOW());
    END IF;
    
    SELECT numeroanimales, numeroplantas, numerohongos, numeroespecies
    INTO numeroanimales, numeroplantas, numerohongos, numeroespecies
    FROM
        (SELECT
        COUNT(CASE WHEN e.tipo = 'Animal' THEN 1 END) AS numeroanimales,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN e.tipo = 'Planta' THEN 1 END) AS numeroplantas,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN e.tipo = 'Hongo' THEN 1 END) AS numerohongos,
        COUNT(*) AS numeroespecies
        FROM especie_terrario et JOIN especies e ON et.idespecie = e.id JOIN terrarios t ON et.idterrario = t.id WHERE t.idusuario = current_id) AS conteo;
    
    UPDATE estadisticas 
    SET 
    numero_especies = numeroespecies,
    numero_animales = numeroanimales,
    numero_plantas = numeroplantas,
    numero_hongos = numerohongos
    WHERE idusuario = (SELECT idusuario FROM terrarios WHERE id = NEW.idterrario);
END
```

---

*EDIT*

Aquí muestro una imagen del error que me da cuando quiero insertar los datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El error es el 1048 y no entiendo el por qué de la situación. He probado a borrar el select de numeroespecies y me da el error con numeroanimales. Creo que no hace bien el insert into.

Comment: Importante agregar el error

Answer (score 0):

El problema en tu código es una confusión entre lo que son las [variables locales](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/declare-local-variable.html) que son las que tienes en el `DECLARE` al principio, y las [variables definidas por el usuario](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html), que son las que declaras con `@` delante. **No es lo mismo ni es igual**. Por ejemplo, éstas últimas persisten durante toda la sesión, mientras que las otras se reinician cada vez que llamas al procedimiento almacenado, la función o el trigger se dispara.

Entonces, en el tercer `SELECT` quita la `@` a todas tus variables, para que se inicien las variables locales:

```
SELECT numeroanimales, numeroplantas, numerohongos, numeroespecies
INTO numeroanimales, numeroplantas, numerohongos, numeroespecies
FROM ...
```

Así debería funcionar, salvo otros errores, que ya nos dirás cuáles son, agregándolos a la pregunta.

#### EDIT

Si sigue sin funcionar, prueba esta consulta aparte y revisa los resultados que arroja:

```
SELECT numeroanimales, numeroplantas, numerohongos, numeroespecies    
FROM
    (SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN e.tipo = 'Animal' THEN 1 END) AS numeroanimales,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN e.tipo = 'Planta' THEN 1 END) AS numeroplantas,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN e.tipo = 'Hongo' THEN 1 END) AS numerohongos,
    COUNT(*) AS numeroespecies
    FROM especie_terrario et JOIN especies e ON et.idespecie = e.id JOIN terrarios t ON et.idterrario = t.id WHERE t.idusuario = current_id) AS conteo;
```

Es evidenta que hay algún problema con esa consulta.

Comment: Acabo de editar la pregunta con tu solución, pero sigue dando el mismo error. No se por qué pasa realmente, me tiene desorientado.

Comment: @AQMR revisa el apartado **EDIT** en la respuesta. Deberías depurar la consulta problemática de forma aislada para ver qué resultados arroja.

Answer (score 0):

Vale, nada, ya está. Era que no puedo poner el mismo nombre de variable que el nombre de la tabla. En los declare cambié los nombres y solucionado.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`aaronibio`@`%` TRIGGER `especie_terrario_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `especie_terrario` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DECLARE rey_escorpion_achivement INT;
    DECLARE current_id INT;
    DECLARE conteo_especies INT;
    DECLARE conteo_animales INT;
    DECLARE conteo_plantas INT;
    DECLARE conteo_hongos INT;
    
    SELECT idusuario INTO current_id FROM terrarios WHERE id = NEW.idterrario LIMIT 1;
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO rey_escorpion_achivement FROM usuario_logro WHERE idusuario = current_id AND idlogro = 3;   
    
    IF rey_escorpion_achivement = 0 THEN
        INSERT INTO usuario_logro (idusuario, idlogro, fecha_adquisicion) VALUES (current_id, 3,  NOW());
    END IF;
    
    SELECT numeroanimales, numeroplantas, numerohongos, numeroespecies
    INTO conteo_animales, conteo_plantas, conteo_hongos, conteo_especies
    FROM
        (SELECT
        COUNT(CASE WHEN e.tipo = 'Animal' THEN 1 END) AS numeroanimales,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN e.tipo = 'Planta' THEN 1 END) AS numeroplantas,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN e.tipo = 'Hongo' THEN 1 END) AS numerohongos,
        COUNT(*) AS numeroespecies
        FROM especie_terrario et JOIN especies e ON et.idespecie = e.id JOIN terrarios t ON et.idterrario = t.id WHERE t.idusuario = current_id) AS conteo;
    
    UPDATE estadisticas 
    SET 
    numero_especies = conteo_especies,
    numero_animales = conteo_animales,
    numero_plantas = conteo_plantas,
    numero_hongos = conteo_hongos
    WHERE idusuario = (SELECT idusuario FROM terrarios WHERE id = NEW.idterrario);
END
```

Comment: Es cierto, y mira que lo dice bien claro en el [Manual de Referencia](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/local-variable-scope.html): *A local variable should not have the same name as a table column.* - *Una variable local no debe tener el mismo nombre que una columna de tabla.* Aunque inicialmente también había una grave confusión entre variables locales y variables definidas por el usuario, como te expliqué en mi respuesta. Esa confusión podría traerte problemas en el futuro si no lo tienes claro.

Comment: Bueno, pero ya está aprendido, muchas gracias!